# Mapstruct with JAXB, @XmlElementRefs

Tags: java, mapstruct

I spent really a lot of time on this, but I can not find the answer. From documentation it seams it should work automatically, but for me it does not. I am facing following problem:

XSD:

```xml
   <xsd:complexType name="AnotherClass">
      <xsd:choice>
         <xsd:sequence maxOccurs="2">
            <xsd:element name="xmlName1" type="SomeClass">
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="xmlName2" type="SomeClass" minOccurs="0">
            </xsd:element>
         </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:choice>
   </xsd:complexType>

   <xsd:complexType name="SomeClass">
      <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element name="value" type="xs:string">
      </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
```

Generated class:

```java
    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(name = "xmlName1", namespace = "http://com.znamenacek", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "xmlName2", namespace = "http://com.znamenacek", type = JAXBElement.class)
    })
    protected List<JAXBElement<SomeClass>> xmlName1sAndXmlName2s;


    public List<JAXBElement<SomeClass>> getXmlName1sAndXmlName2s() {
        if (xmlName1sAndXmlName2s == null) {
            xmlName1sAndXmlName2s= new ArrayList<JAXBElement<SomeClass>>();
        }
        return this.xmlName1sAndXmlName2s;
    }
```

Factory Method:

```java
    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://com.znamenacek", name = "xmlName1", scope = AnotherClass.class)
    public JAXBElement<SomeClass> createAnotherClassXmlName1(SomeClass value) {
        return new JAXBElement<SomeClass>(QNAME, SomeClass.class, AnotherClass.class, value);
    }
```

Mapper:

```java
    @Mapping(source = "source1.source2", target = "target1.target2.xmlName1.value")
    void updateFromSource(Source source, @MappingTarget Target target);
```

I would like to achieve, that value from source2 (String) will add the JAXBElement corresponding to xmlName1 to the xmlName1sAndXmlName2s list and set the value to value from source2.

Hopefully I described my problem clearly

Comment: What does mean `source2` in your question? Please add an example of the `Source` file that is mapped in the `updateFromSource()` method. What is as return result of your mapper? Could you show an example for the `Target` class?

Comment: Basically that is not important. The important thing is that I would like to populate the field in target class which is "hidden" behind List List<JAXBElement<SomeClass>>

Comment: Yes, it does matter. You are trying to solve the problem and don't give enough information about it. Please first take the  [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) How to ask a good question.